# optimize a select query having variable number of columns in where clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

It is buit like this:

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(5000);
            sb.append("SELECT user_id FROM ").append(DEF_USERS_TBL).append(" WHERE user_id='").append(phoneBook.get(0)).append('\'');

    for (int i = 1; i < phoneBook.size(); i++)
    {
        sb.append(" OR user_id='").append(phoneBook.get(i)).append('\'');
    }

    sb.append(';');

    try 
    {           
        Statement s = ...;
        rs = s.executeQuery(sb.toString());
                    ...
            } catch ( ... ) {

                    ...
            }
```

I hear that for MySQL ver > 5.0, innoDB, it would make sense if this was a stored procedure, performance wise. Would it be any faster if I turned this into phonebook.size() individual SELECT queries (and thus, I would be able to store-procedure it) ?

Ty

Comment: Do you mean that your queries are of the type `SELECT user_id FROM DEF_USERS_TBL WHERE user_id=7 OR user_id=13 OR user_id=23 OR ... OR user_id=224 ;`

Comment: You can rewrite is as `SELECT user_id FROM DEF_USERS_TBL WHERE user_id IN (7, 13, 23, ..., 224)` - without any perforance difference. I don't see any reason to break the query into many.

Comment: well, according to http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/139424, having stored procedures instead of in-code queries is faster. Breaking the one big query into many would allow me to make use of a stored procedure in this case. I can rephrase my question for clarity: will this (the use of SP multiple queries instead of just one big query non-SP) be enough to overcome the possible disadvantage of having to run multiple small queries vs. one single bigger query ?